# How to Calculate size of table available in apache ignite node?

Tags: cluster-analysis, h2, ignite

I have created the table in apache ignite & added some data rows. is there any way we can we can calculate size of table ?

Comment: Do you want to get information regarding the consumed memory size or just the rows count?

Comment: @IgorBelyakov , I need consumed memory size by table.

Answer (score 1):

Please, check the [Capacity Planning](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/administrators-guide/capacity-planning) documentation, cause it really depends on multiple conditions, like the types of your fields, indices count, backup copies, etc.

Alternatively, you might serialize your data into binary format and check the size directly from the code:

```
byte[] arr = ignite.configuration().getMarshaller().marshal(new MyObject("val1", "val2")));
System.out.println(arr.length);
```